# Cannot see edges when using wireframe

Tags: 3d-view, edges, wireframe

I cannot see any other edges other than the ones on the picture when in wireframe viewport. This was working properly until today and I am not sure if I accidentally turned off something or not because this happened suddenly. As you can see only 6 of the edges of the cube are possible to be seen (when at least 8, if I did not have X-Ray toggled, should be seen). I already tried to repair the installation, uninstall and reinstall and setting all the settings to the default ones. I then tried installing in another computer and it was working properly.
[image]

**Edit:** When I put it on a top view, I cannot see any of the edges if I have X-Ray turned on (in the pictures below is wireframe on and x-ray off and then both on.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you look in the Viewport shading panel dropdown > XRay slider, could it be that it's set to 1? Wireframe shows through only if it's set to lower value (although that should've been reset if you reinstalled and loaded factory settings)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But the weirdest thing thing is that the edges in the front are also not visible. Only the outline is visible. I am really lost on what could be the issue.

Comment: Default values for XRay slider is 0.5, try to set that value. It means seen-through edges are half-transparent, XRay should remain enabled for Wireframe mode to be proper wireframe with visibility-through. This could be problem with your GPU though you mentioned it worked before

Comment: My thoughts went to GPU as well. When was the last time you updated your graphics drivers? Try updating them, OR if you just updated them, try rolling back to a previous version.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. It was indeed an issue with the newest amd drivers. Rolled back to the previous drivers and have no issues!